# Complex query in mongodb

Tags: java, mongodb

I want to perform a complex mongodb query from java. I have got foure fields `userid`, `statusid`, `dateTO`, and `dateFrom`. The complex query is something like `(userid Or statusid) And (dateFrom < date < dateTo)`. I had the query unitl now:

```
DBObject query = new BasicDBObject();
    ArrayList orList = new ArrayList();
    ArrayList andList = new ArrayList();


    orList.add(new BasicDBObject("user.id", id));
    orList.add(new BasicDBObject("retweeted_status.user.id", id));

    andList.add(new BasicDBObject("date_posted", new BasicDBObject("$gt", dateFrom)));
    andList.add(new BasicDBObject("date_posted", new BasicDBObject("$lt", dataTo)));

    orList.add(new BasicDBObject("$and", andList));

    query = new BasicDBObject("$or", orList);
```

How can I change it to perform the desired query? For example when I tried to make a query to robomongo it looked like:

```
db.coll.find({$and:[{ $or: [ {"user.id":414848505}, {"retweeted_status.user.id":414848505}] },{$and:[{"date_posted":{"$gt":1398948442000}},{"date_posted":{"$lt":1400111999000}}] } ]})
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Is this your desired query?

```
{
    "$and": [
        {
            "$or": [
                {
                    "user.id" : <id>
                },
                {
                    "retweeted_status.user.id": <id>
                }
            ]
        },
        {
            "$and": [
                {
                    "date_posted": {
                        "$gt": <dateFrom>
                    }
                },
                {
                    "date_posted": {
                        "$lt": <dateFrom>
                    }
                }
            ]
        }
    ]
}
```

If yes, try the following:

```
final DBObject userId = new BasicDBObject("user.id", id);
final DBObject retweetedStatusUserId = new BasicDBObject("retweeted_status.user.id", id);
final DBObject or = new BasicDBObject("$or", Arrays.asList(userId, retweetedStatusUserId));

final DBObject greaterThan = new BasicDBObject("$gt", dateFrom);
final DBObject datePostedGreaterThan = new BasicDBObject("date_posted", greaterThan);
final DBObject lessThan = new BasicDBObject("$lt", dateTo);
final DBObject datePostedLessThan = new BasicDBObject("date_posted", lessThan);
final DBObject and = new BasicDBObject("$and", Arrays.asList(datePostedGreaterThan, datePostedLessThan));

final DBObject query = new BasicDBObject("$and", Arrays.asList(or, and));
```

Comment: Yes, this is exactly my desired query.

Comment: Are you sure about your code? It doesn't seem to work properly. I doesn't get what expected when I query to my database.

Comment: Idk, the code yields the same query string as the query above.

Answer (score 0):

```
inside class;

import org.springframework.beans.factory.annotation.Autowired;
import org.springframework.data.mongodb.core.MongoTemplate;
import org.springframework.data.mongodb.core.query.Criteria;
import org.springframework.data.mongodb.core.query.Query;



@Autowired(required = true)
private MongoTemplate mongoTemplate;

// inside some method

List<className> list=null;
            Query query=new Query();
            query.addCriteria(Criteria.where("date_posted").gt(dateFrom);//data type important for passing data 
            query.addCriteria(Criteria.where("date_posted").lt(dateTo);//data type important for passing data 
            query.addCriteria(Criteria.where("retweeted_status.user.id").orOperator(Criteria.where("retweeted_status.user.id")).is(id)); //data type important for passing data// example:Integer.valueOf(id);
            list=mongoTemplate.find(query, className.class);//put your document class name
```